# How to add a class to a div

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have this piece of code in my layout from the tutorial at http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/18 with instructions on how to add fadeout to a bootstrap flash message.

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-block alert-<%= key == :notice ? "success" : key %>" data-dismiss="alert">
      <a class="close">×</a>
      <h4 class="alert-heading"><%= key.capitalize %>:</h4>
      <%= value %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Then the following in a coffeescript file,

```
$ ->
  $(".fadeout").delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
```

The author's instructions says to add "add a class fadeout to the div" and I have tried everything I know of and cant get it to work.  Can someone show me where to add .fadeout to the layout?

Comment: Add the word 'fadeout' to the list of classes in the html div tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am not a ruby guy

But if I am not wrong, you can add the class to the div at the line

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-...
```

i.e

```
<div class="fadeout alert alert-block alert-
```

Comment: Wow, fast responses!  I wish I could accept all the answers because you all where correct!  Since yours showed up first...

Answer (score 2):

The element needs to have the class `.fadeout` for that selector to work.

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="fadeout alert alert-block alert-<%= key == :notice ? "success" : key %>" data-dismiss="alert">
      <a class="close">×</a>
      <h4 class="alert-heading"><%= key.capitalize %>:</h4>
      <%= value %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

They tutorial is using `twitter bootstraop 2.0.0` and they state that `bootstrap` is unable to add effects to the modal.

In `bootstrap 2.1`, they include transitions to their modals:
[Example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

In this case the modal `div` can either include the class `fadeout` or you can download the `js` file from `bootstrap` site and include the class `fade`

If you are wondering how to go about adding the class to the div via jQuery:
[`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Comment: Hey thanks Phil.  The Ruby gem "bootstrap-sass" (which is the standard way to get Bootstrap into Rails) is still at 2.0, hopefully they will update to 2.1 soon.  Thanks for the headsup!